# Numbering in word

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-automation

I am writing an addin for word.

the addin should change a numbered list in word.

original list:

1. foo
   1.1 foobar a
   1.2 foobar b
   1.3 foobar c
2. bar
3. bar X
4. bar Y

The addin deletes 1.1 and 3.

The resulting list looks like:

1. foo
   1.1 foobar b
   1.2 foobar c
2. bar
3. bar Y

The expected result should be:

1. foo
   1.2 foobar b
   1.3 foobar c
2. bar
3. bar Y

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance
tobi

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your list templates of Numbering and set the number value after deleting the entry.

Say after you delete 1.1 in your eg, 1.2 will become 1.1 here you have to set the numbering value back to 1.2

Here is the link for How to set and edit the list templates for Numbering
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34801/Word-Style-Automation

Check the section 5. Set Style to Paragraph